# HTML/JS - Submit button/image must open the same as normal link

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit

You have 3 main buttons on your mouse. LMB, MMB and RMB.
If you click your middle mouse button on an image/hyperlink in any website, it will open new window in the background.

I want the same thing to work, but on a Submit form. I get it - the values are in body of my webiste.

So how can I open the ACTION website in the new background tab?

I tried changing submit to input type="image" but it's the same. Maybe some JS will help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your submit button: `onmousedown="mouseButton(event);"`

```
    function mouseButton(e)
    {
       if(e.button == 1 || e.button == 4)
       {
          var formName = document.getElementById('formID');
          formName.onsubmit = function() {
          window.open("http://localhost/go.php?mode=1")  

          };
       }
    }



echo '<form id="formId" action="http://localhost/go.php?mode=1" method="post">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="val1" value="dr">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="val2" value="'.$kordyarray[0].'">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="val3" value="'.$kordy2.'">';
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="'.$kordyarray[0].':'.$kordyarray[1].'" onmousedown="mouseButton(event)" >';
echo '</form>';
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure it should be onmousedown="mouseButton(event)", and not onmousedown="mouseButton(e)" ?

Comment: I am pretty sure its event, but you can try both.

Comment: Ok, I have something like this:
<input type=submit name=submit onmousedown="mouseButton(event)"> 
and when I click it just redirects me to the action page, nothing "new" happens. (the function is implemented in <script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>) what did I do wrong?

Comment: This should work. One thing to be aware of is Internet Explorer 8 and earlier has different parameters (i.e.the number would be 4 when the middle button is pressed down).

Comment: well for one thing you need quotes around your submit's eg. name="submit"

Comment: add an alert("Hello World"); into the function to make sure it is being executed.

Comment: can you post your entire form up in the question so I can get a better look at it.

Comment: I did add an alert before loop and in the loop, it shows only the one before the loop

Comment: yes @Celeritas is right, Internet Explorer will use 4 instead of 1 so I will fix my code above to accommodate this.

Comment: See below, I posted my js and form

Comment: redirects me to localhost/go.php?mode=1 and it sends the POST data, but it's in the same Firefox Tab

Comment: so it doesn't open a new window?

Comment: same. hmmm, I "include" the js by using this: <script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script> and the js.js file is just the function you gave me. Maybe that's the case? I'm sorry, I don't know JS at all, but sometimes I see "$" symbol before "function" when I see frontend, but I guess that's just json syntax?

Comment: it works for me, make sure you click it with the middle mouse button. If you click it with the left mouse button it will just open in the same window.

Comment: Ohhh, Ok :D I clicked with LMB because I thought the function takes care of it :D hehe, thanks man.

Comment: you can change the function to check if it is a left click (0) or a right click (2) and if its that case don't submit.

Comment: What if I have something like this: http://i.imgur.com/4iebw.png ? Right click won't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Event.button) for the JavaScript used in determining which mouse button is pressed. In the html for your submit button you would have something like `onmousedown="whichButton(event)"`.